# MySQL Select id from to and exclude beginning and ending id

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
+----+-------------------+----------+
| id | channel           | channels |
+----+-------------------+----------+
| m2 | AA-AA             |        4 |
| 1  | TT_1              |        4 |
| 2  | TT_2              |        4 |
| 11 | TT_3              |        4 |
| 12 | TT_4              |        4 |
| m4 | BB-BB             |        4 |
| m3 | CC-CC             |        4 |
| m5 | DD-DD             |        4 |
| 17 | FF-FF             |        4 |
| m1 | EE-EE             |        4 |
+----+-------------------+----------+
```

I need to query and get result from `m2` to next beginning id `m` excluding m2 and m4 in this example...so my ajax send this to mysql:

```
http://server_ip/get_bouquets/m2
```

And needs to get results:

```
1
2
11
12
```

If client send to server:

```
http://server_ip/get_bouquets/m5
```

It needs to get results:

```
17
```

I tryed with:
**Query show here**

```
SELECT id, channel, channels FROM tables WHERE id BETWEEN 'm2' AND '%m%' but i got empty results...any help will be welcome.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Rows in a relational database represent unordered sets. I think you need to rethink your schema. :-(

Comment: You cannot tell the sequence of events from your published data. (sql data is not stored in any specific order)

Comment: This is simple query that returns above table, full query is complicated and very long so it is in this question not required...so i posted above simple table that i need to return results....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do have some way of guaranteeing the sequence of events (and I am simulating here using an auto_increment field) then you could discover the first and next sequence number and test for them

```
DROP table if exists t;
create table t
(sno int auto_increment primary key, id varchar(2),channel varchar(20));
insert into t (id,channel) values
('m2'  , 'AA-AA'),             
( '1'  , 'TT_1' ) ,            
( '2'  , 'TT_2' ) ,                    
( '11' , 'TT_3' ),                      
( '12' , 'TT_4' ),                     
( 'm4' , 'BB-BB'),                     
( 'm3' , 'CC-CC'),                     
( 'm5' , 'DD-DD'),                     
( '17' , 'FF-FF'),                     
( 'm1' , 'EE-EE');

select id 
from t
where sno > (select sno from t where id = 'm2') and sno < 
(select sno from t t1 where left(id,1) = 'm' and sno > (select sno from t where id = 'm2') limit 1);

+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 11   |
| 12   |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a great answer! One way to guarantee order is to provide an automatically generated column with a value based on the other column values. I think that's going to be the most difficult part of this for OP.

Comment: Very smart and very usefull and fast query..thanks, but i need it without autoincrement id (in your example it is autoincrement)...could you please do it with no autoincrement id?

Comment: No. Unless you have some way of guaranteeing the sequence of events in some way it's not possible,This may be in your source data or a result of the query which produces the sample data in the question(row_number perhaps).