# jQuery/Javascript show result from to

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, substr

This is new question that is rewritten using javascript/jQuery of this thread because i can't do this in MySQL directly query.

[MySQL Select id from to and exclude beginning and ending id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254542/mysql-select-id-from-to-and-exclude-beginning-and-ending-id)

So question is simple:

I have array that have received from MySQL query into javascript array:

```
var array = ["m2", "1", "2", "11", "12", "m4", "m3", "m5", "17", "m1"];
```

And need function that accept parameter from what array value to show. For example:

```
function showCategories(marker){

}
```

So in above example if i call `showCategories("m2");` i need to get this:

```
1
2
11
12
```

If i call `showCategories("m5");` i need to get this:

```
17
```

I im currently trying to substr and find index of begin "m2" in first example and find last m index (that is m4) and remove other items from array..is there simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = ["m2", "1", "2", "11", "12", "m4", "m3", "m5", "17", "m1"];

function showCategories(marker) {
  let currentCat = 'n';
  return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (item.indexOf("m") === -1) {
      obj[currentCat].push(item);
    } else {
      currentCat = item;
      obj[currentCat] = [];
    }
    return obj;
  }, {})[marker] || [];
}

console.log(showCategories("m2"));
console.log(showCategories("m5"));
```

### Logic process

As you can see, I am using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and detecting if the value in the item contains an `m` which would indicate a new "category".

Then, I stuff all the values following the new category into an array until another category, again containing `m`, shows up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! Simple, and very usefull...i wish that MySQL query can do this...but it can't...so this javascript function will filter results and do what it needs...thanks...

Comment: @user2631534 if performance is a concern you may want to consider the amount of memory this reduction holds on a large data set. In general the value of reducing is that you're able to look back at items previously stored in the accumulator, which isn't necessary or being done here

Comment: @asthmatic - if that was really an issue, we'd do the reduction once and save it to an external var. Not really an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Find the index of your marker, slice everything after it, then find the first "m" index in that array and slice up to it. All that's left is the numbers in between.

```js
var array = ["m2", "1", "2", "11", "12", "m4", "m3", "m5", "17", "m1"];

function showCategories(marker){
  let start = array.indexOf(marker);
  if (start === -1) return [];
  
  let slicedArray = array.slice(start + 1);
  let end = slicedArray.findIndex(val => val.startsWith("m"));
  return slicedArray.slice(0, end);
}

console.log(showCategories("m2"));
console.log(showCategories("m5"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you could loop through to find the index needed and store the result into a subarray.

One way would be to loop until you find the "m2" by doing:

```
function showCategories(find)
{
  let returnArray = [];
  let start = null;
  if (array.includes(find) //checks if the element exists
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
      if (start == null && array[i] == "m2") //looks for element
      {
        start = i;
      }
      else if(isNaN(Number(array[i]))) //pushes element into array
      {
        returnArray.push(array[i]);
      }
      else if(start != null && !isNaN(Number(array[i]))) //breaks if element after find is not an int
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return returnArray;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but something along these lines would work.